# Big margin between row direction on layout

Tags: javascript, react-native, layout

i'm having trouble formatting one of my screens.
I want to place 3 textinputs in a row, and right below them a button and a checkbox, there's a picture below for more details (it's a crossed box and a question mark as of now, don't mind it i'll fix it later). But i'm getting a huge unwanted margin between the two rows, and i can't get rid of it.
This is the code

```js
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.rowInit2}>
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <TextInput style ={styles.input}
          maxLength={25}
          onChangeText={UserEmail => this.setState({UserEmail})}
          placeholder = 'Item'
          underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'/>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <TextInput style ={styles.input2}
          maxLength={3}
          onChangeText={UserEmail => this.setState({UserEmail})}
          placeholder = 'Cantidad'
          underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'/>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <TextInput style ={styles.input2}
          maxLength={5}
          placeholder = 'Precio'
          onChangeText={UserEmail => this.setState({UserEmail})}
          underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'/>
        </View>
      </View>
    <View style = {styles.row}>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <CheckBox
            checkedIcon={() => {return (<Icon type='feather' name= 'check' />)}}
            uncheckedIcon={() => {return (<Icon type='feather' name= 'check' />)}}
            checked={this.state.checked}
            onPress={() => this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})}
            containerStyle={{backgroundColor:'transparent', width:'20%'}}
          />
      </View>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Icon
        containerStyle ={styles.iconStyle}
        name= 'add-circle'
        color='#0419ba'
        onPress={() => console.log('hello')}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
     </View>
```

and this is the css

```html
export default{
  container:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
  },
  itemVendido:{
    color:'tomato',
    fontWeight:'500',
  },

  rowInit2:{
    flex: 1,
    flexGrow: 1,
    width:'100%',
    marginTop:'5%',
    justifyContent:'space-between',
    flexDirection:'row',
    padding:'2%',
  },
  input:{
    width:'90%',
    borderRadius: 25,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    fontSize:16,
  },
  input2:{
    width:'65%',
    borderRadius: 25,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    fontSize:16,
  },
  row:{
    flex: 1,
    flexGrow: 1,
    width:'100%',
    justifyContent:'space-between',
    flexDirection:'row',
    padding:'2%',
  },
  iconStyle:{
    fontSize:30,
    padding:'3%',
  },
}
```

[this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObqL3.jpg)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new container using flexShrink:1
Thanks anyway!